# Output giving a description of iterator values

Tags: output-formatting

I have a program like this:

```
 Reap[
   Do[
     Do[
       initial2 = Map[# + y &, initial]
     ; weight = Map[#/x &, initial2]
     ; Sow[RandomChoice[weight -> initial]]
     , 1
     ]
   , {x, 1, 2}
   , {y, 1, 3}
   ]
 ]
```

Then, I want to have outputs that show the iterator values, i.e.:

```
{2, 2} -> x=1, y=1
{3, 1} -> x=1, y=2
{2, 2} -> x=1, y=3
 ...
```

The output can be in whatever style.

Comment: Do you want the result from `Reap` in this form? Do you want to format the result later? Do you want to monitor during evaluation?

Comment: Some like monitor during evaluation. I have a large program and I am gonna iterate 1000 times, each time with different values of parameters `{x,y}`. Then I need a description of the outs: I mean the parameters values of each 1000 iterations.

Comment: @Ask8 take a look at `Echo`, `Print`, `PrintTemporary` and friends.

Comment: @Kuba okey! thanks ...I`m gonna look it ..

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care about the exact appearance, how about something simpler:

```
Table[{f[i, j], i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 5}]
```

This gives a list of all the iterators and the values that you have calculated (in this case, `f[i,j]`).